# How do I get access to response cookie received from server?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, typescript, cookies, fetch

For my job I have to create a login on a page. I send my login data to the server using the fetch API and when it was successful, I will receive back a cookie.

However, I do see a cookie sent to me in my response, but I don't know how I can access it or set it on my front-end? Anyone knows how to do this?

**Fetch function**

```
 const submitForm = async values => {
    try {
      const body = {
        user: {
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
        },
      };
// don't mind the strange syntax here, it's a slightly modified fetch function wrapper
      const response = await fetch.post('users/sign_in', {
        body,
      });

  
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  };
```

**Response I get from server, how do I actually get access to this cookie in javascript, or how can I immediately add it as a cookie in my browser?**

[image]

**Cookies of browser is still empty**

[image]

Comment: it's HTTP only, so you can't access it through javascript

Comment: Ok, but isn't it supposed to end up in my cookies then automatically? Or do I misunderstand this?

Comment: your screenshot shows the cookie is being received, so, it is "in" your cookies - look in the application tab under storage->Cookies and you'll see it is there

Comment: They're not stored in my cookies as you can see in my added screenshot

Comment: so, the domain of that cookie is `localhost:3????` - why did you blank it out?

Comment: the domain of the first screenshot is different from localhost (I blanked it out because it is the website I am working on)

Comment: well, why would a cookie for domain `redacted.com` appear in the list of cookies from `http://localhost:3????` - that's like putting milk in your fridge and being surprised it isn't in the oven

Comment: I now understand the problem, I just hadn't worked with it before. Thanks for the help. 

Though leave the attitude next time, you're a prime example of a SO response meme.

Comment: huh? what attitude are you reading? are you being deliberately offended by my metaphor? it's just a metaphor, it's not *attitude* - people use amusing metaphors all the time on SO, the professionally offended are the only ones offended